# Interface texshop with vim

Tags: vim, latex

Any advice on how you would interface texshop on mac osx with vim? I'm using vim quite a lot lately for coding. I find myself now trying to use vim-commands (replace, search, pattern matching, move, etc) when writing documents for latex with texshop and they obviously don't work. However, I don't want to leave texshop altogether, because it has some pretty nice tools I use very often (maybe the most important one is the ability to click the compliled .pdf file while pressing the CMD key on my macbook to jump immediately to the corresponding place in the .tex file).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really help with the question but if you want to use vim I would highly recommend [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) suite. It has a lot of mappings and other latex goodness including completion of references/citations (it loads them from the bib file and gives prompts based on what you've already typed). Also it supports pdfsync forward/backward searching - I use that with Skim. There is some information [here](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2007/12/pdfsync-inverse-searches-in-macvim.html) on how to get that working (and see other posts on that blog).

Are there any other texshop features you would like to reproduce in Vim?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look at vim-latex a day or another, but things are busy these days, so don't really have time to spend time learning a new tool right now. Anyway, it's seems quite nice though, and the time I'll spend learning it will probably be quickly repaid with the time saved by using a vim-based editor...

Comment: "Are there any other texshop features you would like to reproduce in Vim?"

Texshop has the handy feature to compile only the part that has been modified since the last compilation (let's say, a typo, as the most common case). This makes it very fast compared to other windows based latex compilers I used in the past. Is this also possible with vim-latex? 

If you think I should move this question to "Tex, Latex and Friends" on "Stackexchange", please let me know...

Comment: Can you point to any more info on that feature? Texshop just uses whatever latex you have installed (it is not a tex distribution) so if it really does this (which I hadn't heard of before) it must be possible with your own command. Although I must admit from my understanding of TeX I wouldn't think what you describe is possible.

Comment: I tried to find info on that feature, but turned out to be unsuccessful. Probably it does not exist, I was just convinced this is what texshop (or tex-live, which is the tex distribution texshop uses) does because a friend told me so when he advised me to install texshop. Still it seems the compilation is quicker when I only do a minor change to a previous compilation... Anyway, thanks for your help!